# Deciding which activity to open on notification click

Tags: android, android-intent, android-notifications

I'm currently trying to find out, how to specify the destination activity on click on an android notification - **but not until actually clicking the notification**.

I have the following use case: I have an app where the user has to log in before using it. So if the user receives a notification from my app while he is authenticated and using the app in foreground, a click on the notification should lead to lets say `ExampleActivity`. But if the app is in background and a notification is received, a click should redirect to `LoginActivity`, where the user has to authenticate first.

Since the destination activity is specified when creating and setting the Intent to the `NotificationCompat.Builder`, I have no later control over the destination activity.

So if the user is logged in and receives a notification, closes the app and clicks on the notification, he gets redirected to `ExampleActivity`, even though he would have to log in beforehand, which is a security flaw for my process.

I feel like, there should be a common approach on how to solve this kind of problem. Is there a possibility to check if the app is running during click on the notification and decide where to redirect the user to?

Comment: Send it to some ProxyActivity (UI-less, no history) ... and let it decide and start ExampleActivity or LoginActivity in onCreate then finish ... 2nd solution always start ExampleActivity .... if user is logged then continue if not then finsh it and start LoginActivity from ExampleActivity.onCreate

Comment: Similar to the previous suggestion: just go directly to `LoginActivity` which has the logic to decide if the user is already logged in. Alternatively, you can research intent filters. With a properly crafted filters and an Intent, the system can decide which activity to launch.